# New window opening with parent window's controls

Tags: c++, winapi

Sorry for english slaughter but i can't find anything about that.

I'm trying to open an empty window in c++ with winapi but new window opening with parent window's controls like a clone.

```
case VBTN:
{
    vsa1 = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
        L"Window Class",
        L"Test",
        WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        350, 275,
        HWND_MESSAGE,
        NULL,
        GetModuleHandle(NULL),
        NULL);
    ShowWindow(vsa1, 10);
}
```

I tried WS_CHILD style and HWND_MESSAGE in hwndParent but none of them have worked.

Edit:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
HWND hWnd, vsa1;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    WNDCLASSEX vnWind;
    WNDCLASSEX vnEk;
    ZeroMemory(&vnWind, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    ZeroMemory(&vnEk, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    vnWind.cbClsExtra = NULL;
    vnWind.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    vnWind.cbWndExtra = NULL;
    vnWind.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    vnWind.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    vnWind.hIcon = LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(V_ICON_32));
    vnWind.hIconSm = LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(V_ICON_16));
    vnWind.hInstance = hInst;
    vnWind.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WinProc;
    vnWind.lpszClassName = L"Window Class";
    vnWind.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    vnWind.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    //same as vnWind ...
    vnEk.lpszClassName = L"vnTest";
    //same as vnWind ...

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&vnWind))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Reg hatalı", L"Reg", NULL);
        return 1;
    }

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&vnEk))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Reg1 hatalı", L"Reg", NULL);
        return 1;
    }

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
        L"Window Class",
        L"Test Window*",
        WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        270, 80,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInst,
        NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nShowCmd);
    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(msg));

    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    //...
    case VBTN:
    {
        vsa1 = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
            L"Window Class",
            L"Test",
            WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
            350, 275,
            HWND_MESSAGE,
            NULL,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL),
            NULL);
        ShowWindow(vsa1, 10);
    }
    //...
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: My crystal ball says that your WM_CREATE message handler does this.  So you should probably call RegisterClassEx() again to register another window class, named something else than "Window class".

Comment: I changed new class' lpszClassName but it's still opening same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What can i do another than posting whole code ?

Comment: @Polkakorowakurwa: Do what Hans said - post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - a **Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable** example. If your real code is too large, slim it down to its bare logic that still produces the same problem.

Comment: Okay, i added relevant parts of code.

Comment: Name is important as well, especially if you change the WndProc.  The window proc controls behavior of the window class it's registered to control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//same as vnWind ...
vnEk.lpszClassName = L"vnTest";
```

No, that's not enough.  It is not the name that matters, that's just a selector.  It is the content of the WNDCLASSEX struct you pass to RegisterClassEx() that matters.  And *especially* the lpfnWndProc member.  Windows primarily behave different from one another by having different window procedures.  For example, your new window should not treat VBTN message the same.

And above all, it should not treat the WM_CREATE message the same way.  Can't see the code but you are probably creating child windows.  You don't want that to happen in your new window.  It therefore requires a different window procedure, a different value for WNDCLASSEX.lpfnWndProc.

A window class is a cookie cutter.  You can stamp it multiple times with CreateWindowEx(), they all look and taste the same.  Windows has a bunch of built-in cookie cutters, you already know them, like EDIT and LISTBOX, etc.  But if you want to bake a different looking cookie then you need a different cookie cutter.  A new window class with a different window procedure.  You already know how to do that for the first window you created.  Just do it again for the second.

Lose the (WNDPROC) cast btw, that's evil.